# CalculatedColumn or SPServices with jQuery in SP 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices, splist

I need to create a calculated column -say ResCount - based on another `datetimefield` field, ie,assuming if `mydt` is my  datetimefield, from this  field, I need to extract month part and based on month name,I need to assign a number for ResCount.

For example, if its Jan, then ResCount value would be 30 and if its Feb then the ResCount is 60 etc.

Is this possible using calculated column field?
or

Should I use `SPServices` and `jQuery` to determine the selected month when a new item is added on `presaveaction` call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MONTH( [MyDate] )` will return 1 for January,
then use the SharePoint version of the switch/case statement:

```
=CHOOSE( MONTH([MyDate]) , 30 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 )
```

remember: if you are going to work with Dates in JavaScript then January = 0 and December = 11

All SharePoint functions: [www.viewmaster365.com/functions](http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions)

#### Monthnames

`TEXT ( [MyDate] , "mmm" )` returns 'Jan'

`TEXT ( [MyDate] , "mmmm" )` returns 'January'

Comment: That's very helpful information!

Comment: Then close your question, let's reduce that 19.344 open questions to 0 this year

Comment: Danny,thanks for the replies.I am having a chart web part and I need add this rescount as X-field in the chart.But am not able to see this calulcated column in the dropdown. Does the chart web part not support calculalated columns?

Comment: I don't know.. have not used that WebPart for some years